# How to remove .htaccess file

Tags: files

When i try this:
ls -lh:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  401 Sep 20 07:11  .htaccess
```

But i can't remove it.
rm .htaccess

```
rm: cannot remove ‘.htaccess’: No such file or directory
```

or lsof ".htaccess":

```
lsof: status error on .htaccess: No such file or directory
```

So is the file still exist?, and how to remove it.

Comment: Could you try `ls -lb` and add the result? (`-b` prints no-printable chars in "C" style; the idea is checking if there is some invisible char in the file name).

Comment: Also, `ls -ld .` would be useful (the rights to delete a file depend on the flags of the containing directory, not of that of the file itself).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problems. The FileZilla automatically renamed `.htaccess` to  `.htaccess` when uploaded from my local to server. I don't know why it add a space into the filename but renaming the file fixes it.